# unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

помогите, не отправляется форма отправки на почту.

Вот PHP

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->Charset = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setLanguage('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    //От кого письмо
    $mail->setFrom('webmaster@dubinevich.ru', 'Илья Дубиневич');
    //Кому отправить
    $mail->addAddress('bucks20007@gmail.com');
    // Тема письма
    $mail->Subject = 'Привет, новая заявка!';

    //Тело письма
    $body = '<h1>Встречайте супер письмо</h1>';

    if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Имя:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['message']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> '.$_POST['message'].'</p>';
    }

    //Отправляем
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Error';
    } else {
        header('location: thank-you.html');
    }

    $response = ['message' => $message];

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Вот JS

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const formOrder = document.getElementById('form-order');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);
    formOrder.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

    async function formSend(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const error = formValidate(form);

        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const bodyPopup = document.querySelector('.js-modal-container');

        if (error === 0) {
            bodyPopup.classList.add('_sending')
            let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
               method: 'POST',
               body: formData
            })
            if (response.ok) {
                const result = await response.json()
                alert(result.message);
                form.reset();
                bodyPopup.classList.remove('_sending');
            } else {
                alert('Ошибка!')
                bodyPopup.classList.remove('_sending');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Заполните поля');
        }
    }

    function formValidate(form) {
        let error = 0;
        let formReq = document.querySelectorAll('._reg')
        console.log(form);
        for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
            const input = formReq[index];
            formRemoveError(input);

            if (input.classList.contains('_email')) {
                if (emailTest(input)) {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            } else if (input.getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox' && input.checked === false) {
                formAddError(input);
                error++;
            } else {
                if (input.value === '') {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
    function formAddError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.add('_error');
        input.classList.add('_error');
    }
    function formRemoveError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error');
        input.classList.remove('_error');
    }

    //Тест email
    function emailTest(input) {
        return !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/.test(input.value);
    }
})
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну, как минимум делать редирект на html-страницу и пытаться парсить её как json - изначально неудачная идея

Comment: я не очень в этом разибраюсь, и делал все по гайду, но почему-то, не очень) можно ли как-нибудь изменить это так, что-бы работало?

Comment: Блок кода после «Отправляем» ломает вам JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если скрипт должен возвращать json, он не должен выводить ничего больше, ни echo, ни `Location: xxx`

```
//Отправляем
$response = ['message' => $message];
if (!$mail->send()) {
    $response['error'] = 'Email sending error';
}


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```